# Extending contains LINQ method in NH 3

Tags: c#, nhibernate

I have a problem with the integration of NH3 to my project
I need to extend the LINQ provider for contains method.
As a start point, i have followed this tutorial
http://fabiomaulo.blogspot.com/2010/07/nhibernate-linq-provider-exten...
and succeed in the creation of the IsLike method.

My second step was to overload the contains method with a code like
the IsLike.
But this don't work !

I get an error specifying that a current key already exists.

Is there anything special to do to overload contains ?

Thank's by advance.

Answer (score 0):

Some forms of `Contains` are already supported (String.Contains, for example). You are probably clashing with that one.